# Library requirements (speex >= 1.2rc1 speexdsp >= 1.2rc1) not met;

Tags: freeswitch

when I install freeswitch
Error：
configure: error: Library requirements (speex >= 1.2rc1 speexdsp >= 1.2rc1) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.

but I have  install  speex  speex-devel

when I install freeswitch
Error：
configure: error: Library requirements (speex >= 1.2rc1 speexdsp >= 1.2rc1) not met; consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if your libraries are in a nonstandard prefix so pkg-config can find them.

but I have  install  speex  speex-devel
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PHQGa.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLSUU.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)